# How to differentiate between different AWS Environments - Dev, Test, Stage, Production?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I would want to have different environments in AWS. At first I thought of differentiating environments by Tags, tags on AWS Resources. But then I cannot restrict users to change Tags of the machine. What that means is, if I allow them `ec2:CreateTags`, they can not only create tag, but also change tag of any of the resources, since cannot apply a condition on it - say for example if it belongs to a particular VPC or subnet. If I don't allow them the previlege to create tag, then they can launch an instance but their tags are not applied and hence any further operation on the instance is not permitted.

If I want to distinguish between environments by VPC-ID, then for operations such as `ec2:StartInstance` cannot apply a condition to allow the operation only in a specific VPC-ID, but can conditionally allow based on Resource Tag which for reasons in previous paragraph is not convincing.

On AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/differentiate-resources-with-naming.html)  it mentions

> One approach to maintaining this separation was discussed in the [Working with AWS Access Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup_creds.html), that is, to use different accounts for development and production resources.

So it is possible to have one Paying Account for several other accounts which themselves are Paying Accounts? I still don't think multiple accounts for just different environments is a good idea.

How do you generally differentiate among environments for enforcing policies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Different accounts is the way to go.  There are so many places you'll want to create isolation that you'll make yourself crazy trying to do it within one account.  Think about it - there's network controls, all the IAM permissions for all the services, access control lists, tags that have the limitations you describe, and on and on.  Real isolation comes from putting things in different accounts for now.

The last thing you want is some weakness in your dev environment to pivot into your production environment - end of story.  Consider also the productivity benefit of separating prod and dev accounts... you'll never break a prod system from a mistake or experiment in development.

Consolidated billing is the answer to paying for it all.  Easy to setup and track.  If you need more reporting, look into CloudAbility.

Where this gets really interesting is in the space of multiple production and multiple dev environments.  There are a lot of opinions on isolation there.  Some people combine all prod and dev into two accounts, and some put every prod and dev into their own.  It all depends on your risk profile.  Just don't end up like CloudSpaces.

Comment: You don't need different accounts. You can actually just use VPCs or even  network acls to ensure they cannot talk to each other.

Comment: @dvallejo you're absolutely wrong. Separation with different accounts is best practice. end of.

Comment: @ian, yes different accounts are best practices but you can accomplish some isolation within the same account. It can even be naming conventions of a resource. Our dev and integ environments are in the same account whereas the prod account is in a completely separate account. So we accomplish it both ways. It can be a hassle to deal with different accounts. Just my $.02

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do [consolidated billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html), where one account is billed for its own usage + the AWS usage for any other linked account. However, you can not split that bill (e.g. have the master account only pay for EC2 services on a linked account, while having the linked account pay for it's other usage like S3, etc.).

As for differentiating between environments, I've used different [security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) for each one (dev, staging, production) as an alternative to tags, but there are limitations when it comes to enforcing policies. The best option to have full policy control is to use different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest go with with one VPC and use Security Groups for isolation. As your AWS infra grows, you will need Directory Services (Name Servers, User Directory, VM Directory, Lookup services etc.). If you have two VPCs, sharing the Directory Services will not be easy. Also if you need Code Repository (e.g. GitHub) or Build tools (e.g. Jenkins) having three separate VPCs for DEV, Staging and Production will make things really complicated.